# How to count total records with sub queries in WebSql

Tags: web-sql

I have a query now that returns a list of *Group* ID's which have *Logs* assigned to it; which in turn have 1 or more records for that Log.

DEFINITIONS

- Group: An object similar in concept to a folder that can have up to 3 levels of sub groups nested within it. Each Group has its own ID as well as a *parent* ID to indicate if it is a sub group of another group.
- Log: An object that is assigned to a particular Group, which records are created for.

Here is the working query:

```
WITH groupsWithRecords(groupId) AS (SELECT DISTINCT groupId 
    FROM logs 
    WHERE logId IN (SELECT logId FROM savedLogRecords))

SELECT G.groupId
FROM groups G
WHERE parentId=?
AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM groups G2
WHERE G2.groupId IN (SELECT groupId FROM groupsWithRecords)
AND LEFT BETWEEN (SELECT LEFT FROM groups G3 WHERE G3.groupId=G.groupId) AND (SELECT RIGHT FROM groups G4 WHERE G4.groupId=G.groupId)) > 0
```

I now want to modify the query so that it returns both the groupId as well as the total record count for any Logs that belong to that group or any of its sub groups.

EXAMPLE

- Top Group

  - Sub Group A
  - Log X (3 records)

    - Sub Group B
    - Log Y (4 records)

      - Sub Group C
      - Log Z (5 records)

When the ID of the Top Group is provided, the result should include a column to indicate the TOTAL Log records in its **downward** path. In this case 12. But if the ID of Sub Group B is provided, the record count should be 9 because only the records from Logs Y and Z should be included.

I tried to modify the last line of the *groupsWithRecords* sub query to:

`WHERE logId IN (SELECT logId, COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM savedLogRecords))`
But I got an error that two columns were returned where only one was expected.
Other attempts simply result in syntax errors as this query is a bit past my experience level.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Connect By" to work parent child relationships. See the query sample in the URL:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4488e284d181d673c8637f9267f6a538

[image: DB Fiddle Sample Picture]

Comment: I wrongly added the "sql" tag to my question. However, I am trying to do this in a client side websql database. From what I can tell, the CONNECT BY clause is only available in Oracle and thus not an option for me?...